# How to control the URI of triples generated by sem:rdf-insert in MarkLogic?

Tags: xml, uri, marklogic, semantics, triples

Can we customize the URI of the triples? Is there anyway to do so?
As when we insert the triples in ML database it creates duplicates. Same triple with diff URI. So I want to create URI of my own choice. Is that possible in MarkLogic?

Thanks,
Aj

Answer (score 0):

The SPARQL engine will de-duplicate such duplicates, and it is generally something you don't need to worry about much unless you have a high volume of duplicates eating a lot of disk space.

It is a valid question to ask yourself why you have duplicates in the first place. Maybe you are uploading updates of some ontology. Consider assigning those to a dedicated graph, and flushing that graph before reloading the update.

If you insist, you could start managing triples yourself, and embedding them in documents of your own. Personally, I would only do that if you have a set of triples that 'belong' together. For instance, if they represent semantic enrichment data for a document that you loaded into MarkLogic.

You can read more about managed vs embedded triples here:

https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/managed-vs-unmanaged-triples

HTH!